# No module named PyInstaller' after what appears to be a successful install

Tags: python, docker, pip, pyinstaller

I am building a docker image. Within it I am trying to install a number of python packages within one `RUN`. All packages within that command are installed correctly, but PyInstaller is not for some reason, although the build logs make me think that it should have been: `Successfully installed PyInstaller`

The minimal Dockerfile to reproduce the issue:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    unixodbc-dev 


RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir pyodbc==4.0.30 && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir Cython==0.29.19 && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir PyInstaller==3.5 && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir selenium==3.141.0 && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir bs4==0.0.1 

RUN python3 -m PyInstaller
```

The last run command fails with `/usr/bin/python3: No module named PyInstaller`, all other packages can be imported as expected.

The issue is also reproducible with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip

RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir PyInstaller==3.5 
RUN python3 -m PyInstaller
```

What is the reason for this issue and what is the fix?

**EDIT**:

When I run the layer before the last `RUN`, I can see that no PyInstaller is installed, but I can run `python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir PyInstaller==3.5` and then it works without changing anything else.

Comment: in the last line you use `python3.7`. Why are you using that and not `python3`?

Comment: i was using python3.7 and python3, just to see if it makes a difference as python3 is just a symlink to python3.7 and forgot to remove it before pasting it here. but i have removed it now from the post

Comment: it links to the same version until you update to python 3.8, then python3 links to 3.8 and they no longer refer to the same version, causing havoc

Comment: of course, but in this case it is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not fully undestand the reason behind it, it seems like the `--no-cache-dir` option was causing the issue. The dockerfile below builds without an issue:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip

RUN python3 -m pip install PyInstaller==3.5 
RUN python3 -m PyInstaller --help
```

Edit: This seems to be an issue outside of PyInstaller, but with the specific version of pip, see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6963 for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `PyInstaller` but in their [requirements](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/requirements.html) page they wrote:

> If the pip setup fails to build a bootloader, or if you do not use pip
> to install, you must compile a bootloader manually. The process is
> described under Building the Bootloader.

Have you try that in your `Dockerfile`?

(And you're totally right, it should fail... )

Comment: I have for a different architecture, there you first install PyInstaller using pip and then you compile the bootloader. but you can run `python3 -m PyInstaller` on these platforms, even if creating a bundle fails